# how to specify cell execution in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, execution

I want to run **cell 2,3,etc** and get the output then **execute cell 1**.

I am wondering whether it is possible?

Comment: You may want to look into using jupyter lab.  I believe this functionality is available with the same style of interface you are used to.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use this order occasionally  or always? You certainly can click and run cells any order you want. It can be very useful for learning and developing. If you want them to always run that order it is best to reorder the cells. Avoiding a ‘hidden state’ of your notebook is a practice encouraged for reproducibility.

Comment: And since @James brought up JupyterLab, I’ll add it is particularly powerful for easily reordering cells. You can open two views into the same notebook by right clicking on the notebook’s name tab. Then you can scroll to a different location in one view and drag and drop cells across the two views to restructure the notebook.

Comment: I can manage the code myself. But the problem starts when someone else look at it. That is why I am looking for a solution that doesn't require any installation or changing the notebook. Changing the orders was also to avoid any confusions then the code goes straight forward to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with extensions, you can also reorder them such that the first cell you want to execute becomes the final cell and so this executes in sequential order.

Have a look on [init_cell](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/init_cell/README.html) extension. It allows you to mark some cells and run them on load\demand.

Here is the [installation instructions](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

Comment: I work in colab notebook. I get invalid syntax error for " jupyter contrib nbextension install --user" Also this solution is for the system that I work not others who run my code. right! I am looking for a command or like table of content and order them to be executed. If possible.

Comment: Yes this extension is simply for your system and will simply orchestrate the running order. Are you following step by step as listed? Can you provide any error logs?

Comment: This is the error in the second step. " jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax" , The thing is that is not a useful method if I upload the code  or sent it to anyone.

Comment: Add a prefix '!' to the jupyter.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has helped so that others can benefit.